# PHP Disk Used Space - Dependency

Tags: php, diskspace, linux-disk-free

I'm using php to try and work out the total, available & used space on a disk.

This is the code I'm running :

```
$total = (disk_total_space("/")/1024);
$available = (disk_free_space("/")/1024);
$used = ($total - $available);

echo "$total\n\n";
echo "$available\n\n";
echo "$used\n\n";
```

and the output returned :

305594616

293030828

12563788

A df of the same partition returns the same values of the Total and Available, but used is different.

```
 df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      305594616 11632392 293030828   4% /
```

Why does php show `12563788` and df show `11632392` ?

Is there anyway to get accurate values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use some ext file system, there is by default an area reserved for root user (5%, can be checked or changed with the `tune2fs` tool, for example). This is why total, used and free don't match up.

There is no reliable way with PHP functions to get the used space at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of this. For what I'm going having the used value slightly higher won't be an issue.